# How to fix a multithreaded unit test that hangs our TeamCity build?

Tags: c#, teamcity, rhino-mocks

We've faced with the problem that one of our unit tests fails a few times for a day during CI on TeamCity. We use MSTest and RhinoMocks. It's almost impossible to reproduce it on dev machine (maybe because of 1 cpu PC on dev machine, i don't know).

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("UnitTest")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(AggregateException))]
public void TestRiskDataStagingThrowAggregateException()
{
    DataStagingThrowException(typeof(DeskRiskDataPump));
}

protected void DataStagingThrowException(Type dataPumpType)
{
    // set expectations
    foreach (IUploader uploader in StubUploaders)
    {
        uploader.Expect(x => x.Upload(StubDataProvider)).Repeat.Once().Throw(new Exception("BANG!!!"));
    }

    Repository.ReplayAll();

    IDataPump datapump = new DataPumpFactory().GetDataPump(dataPumpType, StubDataProvider, StubUploaders, StubDistributor);

    // Execute
    // the test can hang here!!!
    datapump.Execute();

    Repository.VerifyAll();
}

StubDataProvider = Repository.Stub<IEnumerable<TRecord>>();
StubUploaders = new List<IUploader>();
StubDistributor = Repository.Stub<IDataDistributor>();

StubUploaders.Add(Repository.Stub<IUploader>());
StubUploaders.Add(Repository.Stub<IUploader>());
StubUploaders.Add(Repository.Stub<IUploader>());
```

Class which implements `IDataPump` is a little bit complecated and i'm afraid to post it here:) In general it implements Producer-Consumer pattern and launches a few processes in different streams, something like this

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];

// Start adding to the queue
tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(Produce);

// Start draining the queue in parallel
tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(ConsumeCreditRisk);
tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(ConsumeTrancheRisk);
tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(ConsumeRatesRisk);

// Wait to complete
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    .....
    throw;
}

private void ConsumeCreditRisk()
{
    _creditRiskUploader.Upload(_creditRiskBuffer.GetConsumingEnumerable());
}
```

In our case uploaders are stubs which suppose to throw an exception, and it should be catched as an aggregate exception. But according to logs it sometimes hangs on the stub method Upload.

Do you have any suggestion what can cause the problem?

Comment: It's almost certainly some sort of concurrency problem. Do you have your own locking code or are you using the collections from System.Collections.Concurrent to synchronize the tasks access to data? I'd recommend to add a unit test loop runner that executes your test locally forever.. that should allow you to (eventually) experience the same hang even when the debugger is attached.

Comment: thank you for advice, i'll try it. For buffer organizing we use BlockingCollection. This code passed complicated loading test... it should hang on so easy unit test

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to provide a timeout to any multithreading tests to prevent deadlocks from screwing up your build. This is a workaround though.